# JSONPath: Extracting subset of array produces weird results

Tags: java, groovy, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have this json:

```
{
  "push": {
    "changes": [
      {
        "commits": [
          {
            "hash": "b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And, I have the follow jq, code that works fine

```
cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/sterling/pipeaas on master [+!?]
$ jq -re '.push.changes[].commits[].hash ' push.json # golden hash
b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4
```

which produces what I want.

I now try to use the JSONPath equivalent and this is where it gets strange:
If I [try it here](https://jsonpath.com/), I get and array size 1 with my hash:

```
$.push.changes[*].commits[*].hash
[
  "b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4"
]
```

So, that that yields and array, then I can just index that array, right?:

```
$.push.changes[*].commits[*].hash[0]
[
  "b"
]
```

I get the letter `b` - so now it's treating the string as a character array.

So, maybe it's an implementation problem. I tried this same path expression in groovy and I get something yet also different:

in jsonpath.groovy

```
@Grab(group = 'com.jayway.jsonpath', module = 'json-path', version = '2.4.0')
import com.jayway.jsonpath.*

stuff = JsonPath.parse(new File('push.json')).read('$.push.changes[*].commits[*].hash')
println(stuff)
```

```sh
$ groovy jsonpath.groovy

[b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4]
```

Ok, we have our array again. Now, let's get that 1 element:

```
@Grab(group = 'com.jayway.jsonpath', module = 'json-path', version = '2.4.0')
import com.jayway.jsonpath.*

stuff = JsonPath.parse(new File('push.json')).read('$.push.changes[*].commits[*].hash[0]')
println(stuff)
```

```sh
$ groovy jsonpath.groovy 
[]
```

So now, it's like the array has nothing at all?!

So, how do I get this single array item as a path expression?

Comment: FWIW, if [you use Jmespath](https://jmespath.org/), the expression `push.changes[0].commits[0].values(@)[0]` outputs `"b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4"`.

Comment: I don't have a choice. Using JSONPath is necessary for integration

Comment: I'll be happy to be proven wrong, but I don't think it can be done with jsonpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.push.changes[0].commits[0].hash
```

To get the "first" hash in that hierarchy.

`[*]` behaves like the spread-operator in Groovy

Comment: I literally discovered the exact same thing now. If I wanted a flattened list, element 0, how might I do that? If you can update the answer that'd be great. I mean, you answered it correctly so you win the prize, but some color would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. But, the behavior of your expression is correct. your `commits` is an array so you can behave it like `commits[*]` or `commits[0]`. But the `hash` field is not array. Because of that `JSONPath` treats it like `arrays of characters`.

I guess you want to get the right `hash` from `commits` array. so you just need your expression to be like:

`$.push.changes[*].commits[1].hash`

then assuming your JSON objet is like:

```
{
  "push": {
    "changes": [
      {
        "commits": [
          {
            "hash": "b194ab92186b94de3f9493818c353e9bbedb38d4"
          },
          {
              "hash":"secondHash"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the result would be :

```
[
  "secondHash"
]
```